# AngularJS Formly - Repeating Section Validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-formly

Angular-formly.com has an example of how to do a repeating section: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section

If you were to modify the `Name of Investment` field and mark it required, it is not being flagged (thus not highlighting the field red) upon pressing the submit button.  I believe this should happen since it is required.

Looking into the Form output toward the bottom of the screen you can see how `$submitted` is still set to `false` which means that the screen doesn't believe that it needs to worry about marking the field red.  If you manually click in the field and click out (without typing anything) then the field correctly is highlighted red.

This repeating behavior is created via inner arrays of fields.  Could this be messing with how the submit button works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the example. Since that example was originally written, angular-formly added a behavior that improved this use case. Now, all the sections can share the same `NgFormController` instance by simply passing an existing `NgFormController` via the `form` attribute. You see that change in the example. Good luck!

Comment: I also disabled the submit button when the form is invalid to make it more clear when the form is invalid (you'll notice that the radio buttons are required, and so it starts out as being disabled.

Comment: Just to be clear, the change you are talking about is on the `formly-form` in the `repeatSection` template?

Comment: Cool, I got the fix implemented and that looks good now.  Validation is now being applied for all of the repeated sections.  Random question...the validation (Required for instance) is only being checked on the newest created section and if it fails (and the required message should be shown) it actually shows the message on that field within all of the repeated sections...even if that particular section's field is also populated.  Any ideas?

Comment: To better narrow my question from before...looking at your repeater example again, all of the fields have the same model name just in a different element of the `investments` array.  Is it possible to give these fields a unique name? (`investmentName_1`, `investimentName_2`, etc)  My validation is flagging the same field among all of the repeated sections whenever one of them fails validation.  I have a feeling it is because they all have the same model name and thus my validation code is flagging all of them.